# -C# / JAVA- Get PID on Applications run in CMD

Tags: c#, java

poor english sorry

How to find a java PID?

```
Process Server = new Process();
Server.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
Server.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
Server.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Server.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
Server.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Server.Start();

StreamWriter InputCommands;
InputCommands = Server.StandardInput;
InputCommands.WriteLine(@"cd ""D:\Other\Server""");
InputCommands.WriteLine(@"java -jar Server155.jar");
```

can be input

```
InputCommands.WriteLineAsync("status");
```

i try to use

```
Server.StartInfo.FileName = "java.exe";
Server.StartInfo.Arguments = " -jar Server155.jar"
```

to direct get PID but java path changed to 'C:\windows\system32' or 'C:\Users\name'

but also can't input anymore and the jar can't to load other files

java -jar "D:\JavaServer\test.jar"

Correct Path @ .bat run

```
D:\JavaServer\test.jar
D:\JavaServer\file\....
```

WIN key + R to run java

```
D:\JavaServer\test.jar
C:\windows\system32\file\....
```

cmd without CD path

```
D:\JavaServer\test.jar
C:\users\username\file\....
```

how to get PID and run in Correct Path?

thx for help

Comment: I could not understand what was the problem with launching the java executable directly... Can you elaborate?

Comment: if run java on WIN+R java will search C:\windows\system32 for other files. if run java on CMD java will search C:\Users\username. if run java on my C# program..will be search the program path. poor english sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer is very simple. 
Use `Server.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory` to specify where is the "current directory" of your program.

Then, when you run it, and the java program would try to read (or load, or whatever) files which it assume to be in the same directory (as the jar file) - that directory is actually the `WorkingDirectory`.